# Is spring security really needed for developing a react js based web application?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

What are spring securities need to be implement while creating react js based web application?.
what is the current trend?Kindly reveal me if someone has really experience in this field ,especially from spring boot back end developers.

Comment: react js is front-end should be serious about your backend and its depends on what technology you are using in your backend and mostly framework do some security work by it self now its depends on what type of security you want in your product.

Comment: The question is very vague and primarily opinion-based.  What security you use is based on what technology stack you are using and what your requirements are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since react-js is only a frontend web framework, it can't handle the backend services. In my opinion integrating react-js frontend with spring-boot at the backend will be a great choice for a project but it always depends on what type of application you are building.

Spring boot provides many features for security like **Password Hashing**, **Role based Authentication**, **Remember-me**, **HTTP Authorization** and many more.
The best part about these features is that they can be configured and customized based on your needs and what suits your application the best